# I have awaited the campgrounds.deleteMany() function but it is still buffering after 10seconds

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

```
 const path = require('path')
 const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 const cities = require('./cities')
 const Campground = require('../views/models/campground')
 const {descriptors,places} = require('./seedhelpers')

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/yelp-camp', {
      useNewUrlParser:true,
      //useCreateIndex:true,
      //useFindAndModify:true,
      useUnifiedTopology:true
 })


 db = mongoose.connection;
 db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection ERROR"));
 db.once("open", ()=>{
 console.log("Database connection open")
 })

 const sample = array => array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length )]

 const seedDB =  async()=>{
     await Campground.deleteMany({});
     for(let i=0; i<50; i++){
     const random1000 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
     const price = Math.floor(Math.random()*20)*10
     const camp = new Campground({
         author:'63dbcd28bd0379985929400c',
         location: `${cities[random1000].city}, ${cities[random1000].state} `, 
         title: `${sample(descriptors)} ${sample(places)}`,
         image:'https://source.unsplash.com/collection/483251',
         description:"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus labore magnam          reiciendis ex corrupti, nobis, obcaecati alias laboriosam voluptatum, cumque dignissimos accusamus? Voluptatibus accusamus voluptatum nulla vel doloribus, delectus voluptatem?",
         price
         })
         await camp.save()
     }
}

 seedDB().then(()=>{
 mongoose.connection.close();
})
```

it is showing that it is buffered after 10seconds. but i awaited it here. I want to delety all campgrounds
and make a set of new campgrounds every time i run the file. so i have given it.

Answer (score 0):

When Mongoose says it's buffering commands it means that you're issuing them before the connection has been established. Using `await` on the command doesn't solve that.

Your issue is likely due to the use of `localhost` in the connection string, which may resolve to the IPv6 address of that hostname (`::1`). MongoDB typically only listens on the IPv4 equivalent, `127.0.0.1`, which means that Mongoose (and the underlying MongoDB library) are trying to connect to the wrong address.

The fix would be to explicitly use an IPv4 address in your connection string:

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/yelp-camp
```